# Is it possible to implement Android N (Preview Version) on new Lenovo Moto G4 Plus?

Tags: rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat

Is anyone tried to experiment to install Android N update in Moto G4 Plus ? or if it does installed successfully, then please guide us towards the procedures for that.

Comment: To be exact, there's no source code for Android N at the moment, so there's no way to port it to other roms, even to older Nexus devices. Installing ROM for other devices won't work as have been mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install a firmware on a device that it isn't made for. This will (permanently) brick the device.

However, there is an Xposed module called [Android N-ify](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=66036966&postcount=1) that will make your phone look like Android N. Root access is required.

Comment: somewhere i seen in video, a guy using nexus 6P and showing features of Android N ? may i know what he actually did it to his device ? and also as lenovo company confirms that the new moto g4 plus will be upgraded to android N till O, so may i your opinion please, do you believe on that statements of future upgradation ? is moto g4 plus capable enough ?

Comment: @GovindTank sorry, I don't know if your device will get the Android N update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get Android N update in Moto G 4 Plus. Depend on your base band. [image: you can find the zip on XDA and flashing instructions too.]